# Install rJava on Ubuntu failed

Tags: java, r

I try to install rJava package following
"sudo R CMD javareconf" and in R "install.packages('rJava', type = "source"), but it does not work.

First, I installed my Java in this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

In my .bashrc, I have been setting

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Then

```
     sudo R CMD javareconf 
*** JAVA_HOME is not a valid path, ignoring
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_111
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

Then

```
    Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/sunxd/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/sunxd/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rJava’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpxpdHF7/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rJava", type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply start by installing `r-cran-rjava` from terminal

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

Then from R, simply run this

```
install.packages('rJava')
```

Comment: In R 3.6.1, I had to get that package from a PPA (credit: https://askubuntu.com/a/1116015/48105), then logout/login and restart my R session before rJava could finally be installed.

Comment: In R 4.*, use this first `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+`

Answer (score -1):

I tried several of the above options, but nothing worked for me.
Then I tried

```
install.packages("rJava",dependencies = TRUE)
```

and it worked like a charm.