# R: Cannot install rJava; what is r-api-3.4?

Tags: software-installation, java, r

I am on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine with R version 3.5.1, installed following [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/). I am trying to install the CRAN package **rJava**, which I do the following way (as seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858961/install-rjava-on-ubuntu-failed)):

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

However, I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-rjava : Depends: r-api-3.4
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But when I try:

```
sudo apt-get install r-api-3.4
```

I get:

```
E: Package 'r-api-3.4' has no installation candidate
```

How to overcome this problem with `r-api-3.4`? Basically, I need to install `rJava` to be able to install and use `XLConnect`... In Ubuntu 16.04, I had no problems whatsoever...

**EDIT:**

Apparently, `r-api-3.4` should be provided by `r-base-core`. I do have `r-base-core` installed in its newest version, why do I still see errors then?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the issue is that, when you were trying to install `r-cran-rjava`, it required you to have R 3.4 on your system (i.e. the version of the official Ubuntu repositories) rather than R 3.5.

It looks like this can be an issue for other packages, like `rkward` for example (it also asks for `r-api-3.4` and can't resolve the dependency).

To fix that, you might have to add an extra PPA that provides newer version of extra R packages for the 3.5 branch, like Michael Rutter's 
[cran2deb4ubuntu_3.5](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u3.5), which seems to be the reference. (It currently contains `r-cran-rjava` in its version `0.9-10-3cran1ppa0bionic0`)

This might do the trick:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-cran-rjava
```